# LINQ lambda expression for many-to-one inner join involving max()

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, max, many-to-one

I have the following schema:

```
Table1
ID int

Table2
ID int
Table1ID int
Datetime datetime

Table3
ID int
Table2ID int
Name varchar(255)
```

All columns are `not null`. How do I write the following SQL query in LINQ using lambda expressions?

```
select Table1.*
    from Table2
    inner join (
        select Table1ID, max(Datetime) as Datetime
        from Table2
        group by Table1ID
    ) a on Table2.Table1ID = a.Table1ID and Table2.Datetime = a.Datetime
    inner join Table3 on Table2.ID = Table3.Table2ID
    inner join Table1 on Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID
    where Name = 'me'
```

**EDIT:**

I am using LINQ to EF. I have tried

```
var myEntities = new MyEntities();
var a = myEntities.Table2.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Datetime }).GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => new { Id = x.Key, Datetime = x.Max(y => y.Datetime) });
var b = myEntities.Table2.Join(a.ToList(), x => new { Id = x.Table1Id, x.Datetime }, y => new { y.Id, y.Datetime }, (x, y) => x.Id);
return myEntities.Table3.Where(x => x.Name == "me" && b.Contains(x.Table2Id)).Select(x => x.Table2.Table1).ToList();
```

but it comes back with

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

highlighting the last line above. The stack trace shows it is ToList() throwing this exception.

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to EF? Something else? Also, what have you tried? Why didn't that work?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; it was that

```
var b = myEntities.Table2.Join(a.ToList(),
```

should be

```
var b = myEntities.Table2.Join(a,
```

Also, the query should be

```
var myEntities = new MyEntities();
var a = myEntities.Table2.Select(x => new { x.Table1Id, x.Datetime }).GroupBy(x => x.Table1Id).Select(x => new { Table1Id = x.Key, Datetime = x.Max(y => y.Datetime) });
var b = myEntities.Table2.Join(a, x => new { x.Table1Id, x.Datetime }, y => new { y.Table1Id, y.Datetime }, (x, y) => x);
return b.Join(myEntities.Table3, x => x.Id, y => y.Table2Id, (x, y) => new { x.Table1, y.Name }).Where(x => x.Name == "me").Select(x => x.Table1).ToList();
```